# Software to replace multiple text strings at once

Tags: windows

I'm looking for Windows software which can replace **multiple text strings**, in single or multiple text files, at once.

With ability to save or re-use **rules**.

Windows, Free, GUI, No RegExp.

Comment: "Multi String Replacer" https://windowsportableapps.blogspot.com/2017/07/multi-string-replacer.html

Answer (score 1):

**Automation Workshop** Free Edition can do that and much more - https://www.automationworkshop.org/

- Free for personal use
- GUI
- It supports RegEx, but also works without it
- It works on all Windows versions
- Tasks created with AW can be reused

**The Text Actions you may find useful:**

- Read from file
- Find and replace text
- Write to file

Comment: Replacing a text with an automation tool is a someting over-complicated. This is what I need: https://i.imgur.com/6EloEoD.png . Actually I "have" the answer except it's Shareware, but wanted to know something new.

Answer (score 1):

"Multi String Replacer"

https://windowsportableapps.blogspot.com/2017/07/multi-string-replacer.html

- GUI
- Replace multiple strings at once
- String Swapping functionality (Replace WordX with WordY and WordY with WordX)
- RegEx (Regular Expressions can be used)
- Save/Load user Settings
- Export Output into ".txt" File